# taking four user inputs and comparing with strcmp in C

Tags: c, string

Hello I am a complete beginner in a university course for C programming. I am trying to compare 4 inputs for exact matches using strcmp. The code only take into account the first two though. Is it possible to compare two strcmp values to compare 4 inputs?

Comment: Post your code to improve this question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is not very clear what you are asking. May I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the results via `&&`.

```
if (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0 && strcmp(str1, str3) == 0 && strcmp(str1, str4) == 0) {
    printf("They match!")
}
```